# how to perform rolling update from gitlab-runner

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

I want to perform **kubernetes** rolling update from **Gitlab CI**. My idea is running some `kubectl` commands from **Gitlab CI** pipeline on my **kubernetes** AWS machine which has been registered as `gitlab-runner`.

Below is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` config.

```
rolling-update:
    script:
        -  kubectl set image deployment web-server web=web:latest
    stage: deploy
    tags:
        - k8s
    when: manual
```

However, every time I run the pipeline, I get error

> error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)

I guess the more general question is how can I run `kubectl` on `gitlab-runner`?

Comment: Let me guess, you run kubernetes in `EKS`? then you need set your aws credentials, then run `kubectl` command

Comment: The cluster does sit on AWS, but I create it by using **kubeadm**. How can I add AWS credentials to Gitlab?

Comment: Do you have the Kubernetes Cluster configured for the repo in which the `.gitlab-ci.yml` lives? Also, inserting `kubectl config view` before that `kubectl set image` may be helpful, even if you don't post it here, you'll at least know the situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. The `gitlab-runner` environment config is not correctly set. I add those commands to my pipeline and it works fine.

```
sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf
```